# jquery fullcalendar prepend characters to title output

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have an implementation of fullcalendar that uses a SQLExpress for storing events. What I would like to do is.

1. If a certain condition is met. I want to prepend characters to the event title. These need to be displayed on the 
   main calendar display.

Example: I have a drop down on the add event dialog that is called "Payment Type" with options of "Private Pay" or "Insurance"

When the event render is called I have the following code:

```
switch (event.paymenttype) {
            case 'private pay': event.title = "P " + event.title; break;
            case 'insurance': event.title = "I " + event.title; break;
```

The code prepends the "P " and the "I " to my event title but can only be seen when I click the event in the update dialog.

I wish to see it on the main calendar view.

I have a jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/OhioGTO1969/9wxw85r0/1/

Thanks for looking!

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that during eventRender, the HTML which will be used to show the event has already been created. You have access to it via the `element` parameter of the callback.

Therefore, amending the `event` object doesn't do anything because fullCalendar has already used it and finished with it in order to create the HTML. It takes no notice of any changes you make to the event object at this point in time. The reason it's available in the callback is so you can pick anything extra you want from it and then adjust the HTML element before it's placed on the calendar.

Now, you could use eventRender to adjust the HTML object - extract the element which contains the description, modify it, and write it back into the main element. However, since you simply want to alter the title property, there is an easier way:

The `eventDataTransform` callback runs after the events have been fetched from the event source, but before the event object is used to generate any HTML. You can use it to make changes to the event object which is then used for rendering. This is perfect for your use case.

You can set it as follows:

```
eventDataTransform: function(event) {
  switch (event.paymenttype) {
    case 'private pay': event.title = "P " + event.title; break;
    case 'insurance': event.title = "I " + event.title; break;
  }
  return event;
}
```

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform for details of the two callbacks and how they differ.

Your JSFiddle doesn't actually work because you haven't mocked the ajax calls (so they fail), so I can't prove the code above, but nevertheless here's an updated version of it containing my code: https://jsfiddle.net/9wxw85r0/3/ . You can try it for yourself in your real solution.